# алгоритм перечисления всех m-последовательностей из 0 и 1

Tags: алгоритм, fortran

нужен алгоритм перечисления всех m-последовательностей из 0 и 1 (например, для m=5, от 00000 до 11111). Хорошо бы типа в фортране :)
спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Это просто двоичные представления для чисел от 0 до 2<sup>m</sup>-1. То есть алгоритм элементарен: делаем цикл по `i` от 0 до 2<sup>m</sup>-1, на каждой итерации рассматриваем двоичное представление `i` (ширины m) как очередную последовательность.

Какие-то усложнения реализации возможны для слишком больших значений m, но и там не составит труда реализовать "длинную арифметику" вручную, ибо нас интересует только одна-единственная операция - инкремент на 1.

Comment: обнаружил: в f90 есть функции работы с битами так что всё ОК. Спасибо